# How to REALLY put a window above all others -- Linux PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, window, layer

I am trying to make a window that will stay on top of lxpanel.

I got the window loaded up, using

```
import gtk

myWindow = gtk.Window()

myWindow.set_keep_above(True)

myWindow.show_all()
```

This does indeed give me a window that stays on top, it even manages to slide over LXpanel when dragged.  It will even stay on top when other windows are clicked, but when I click on LXpanel itself, lxpanel jumps to the top, pushing my window behind it.  How can I make this window REALLY stay on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by your window manager, and you can't really do much about it.

(In my testing, it seems Xfwm4 and Fluxbox puts keep-above windows above dock/panel windows, despite what EWMH [recommends](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s07.html#STACKINGORDER), but perhaps your WM doesn't.)

There is, however, a very limited workaround: if you assume that the user will never have more than one dock/panel, you can set your window to be [transient](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-transient-for) for that dock window. Usually (again, depending on window manager) this will keep your window above the dock window.

---

**Update:** In X11, you can set transient windows even if they are not in the same process. The simplest way I've found is using libwnck to get the XID of the panel window, then importing that to GDK using [gdk_window_foreign_new](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#gdk-window-foreign-new). Of course, this won't work in non-X systems.

```
import wnck
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
# BUG: There needs to be a small delay between the previous line and the next;
# otherwise get_windows returns an empty list.
windows = screen.get_windows()
panel = windows[1] # For example
panel_xid = panel.get_xid()

import gtk
window = gtk.Window()
window.show_all()
window.window.set_transient_for(gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new(panel_xid))
```

Comment: I thought I could only make things transient to their parent?  I eagerly await to try this out when I get home.

If something is transient, doesn't that mean it's the only thing can can have focus?  Or is that modal?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how to refer to lxpanel with myWindow.set_transient_for(parent)

If I was writing my own panel, I could easily set this up in a parent-child relationship, but how do I assign myWindow to be a child process of any other window not related to the same program?

Comment: There we go, this filled-in all my ignorance holes.

Answer (score 1):

In the [reference page](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-keep-above) says that `gtk.Window.set_keep_above` is just a request to the window manager that might not be honored, so I'd say that is unlikely to make that happen under all circumstances.

Anyway, it gives also an interesting piece of information:

> You can track the above state via the gtk.Widget "window_state_event" signal.

Maybe you can try to set a callback for that signal to make sure `gtk.Window.set_keep_above` is called again as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_POPUP)
```

Comment: this window should not have a title bar